# What does '$?' this mean in perl

Tags: perl

What does below if condition means in perl:

```
  if($? != 0 ){
  }
```

please explain.

Comment: [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: doesn't make sense that someone downvoted you, this isn't easy to find on google unless you know how. I +1'ed you to fix that gross travesty of justice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These variables are documented in the `perlvar` pages : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

```
$?
```

> The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (`` ) command, successful call to wait() or waitpid(), or from the system() operator. This is just the 16-bit status word returned by the traditional Unix wait() system call (or else is made up to look like it). Thus, the exit value of the subprocess is really ($?>> 8 ), and $? & 127 gives which signal, if any, the process died from, and $? & 128 reports whether there was a core dump.